# how to access class javascript on html?

Tags: javascript

how can i call getting  function on this class? for example i have this kind of button
for example if i have a class like this

**javascript.js**

```
class Hero {
   a=1;
   b=2;
}

class BokunoHero extends Hero {

   gettingValue(){
     return alert(a + b);
   }
}
```

**functioncall.html**

```
<button id="clickmeplease" onclick="whatinsidehere?"></button>
```

what inside the onclick on onclick button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use a function to create an instance and call the method :**

```js
const getvalue = () => {
  let MyBokunoHero= new BokunoHero();
  console.log(MyBokunoHero.gettingValue());
};

class Hero {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
  }
}

class BokunoHero extends Hero {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  gettingValue() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="clickmeplease" onclick="getvalue()">CLICK ME</button>
```